# honda unircorn missing problem when increase in throttle

Tags: honda, unicorn

i have a honda unicorn 
when i increase the rpm to 5000 there is a missing problem but when i change the gear(UP or DOWN) or decrease the rpm it will gone. again it happens when i increase

Comment: Am not sure, but it sounds like the clutch is slipping.

Comment: Could you please explain what is missing problem.?

Comment: Has the misfire started recently?  When was the vehicle last serviced?  Which engine, fuel type and model year is the vehicle?